# node.js, passport-wordpress: The required "redirect_uri" parameter is missing

Tags: wordpress, node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

Trying to create a demo using passport-wordpress
https://www.npmjs.org/package/passport-wordpress

passport-wordpress allows you to login to a node.js app using your credentials at wordpress.com

I set up my Wordpress app at developer.wordpress.com/apps:

> ```
> OAuth Information
> Client ID <removed>
> Client Secret <removed>
> Redirect URL  http://greendept.com/wp-pass/
> Javascript Origins    http://wp-node2.herokuapp.com
> Type  Web
> Request token URL https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token
> Authorize URL https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize
> Authenticate URL  https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authenticate
> ```

In my node.js app:

```
    var CLIENT_ID = <removed>;
    var CLIENT_SECRET = <removed>;
    passport.use(new WordpressStrategy({
    clientID: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate({ WordpressId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return done(err, user);
    });
  }
```

When I try to authorize, it goes to this URL (as one line, I've divided into two here for readability):

> https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize?
>
> response_type=code&redirect_uri=&client_id= removed

I can see that the redirect_uri is missing in that URL, so it's not surprising that I get this error:

> Invalid request, please go back and try again.
>
> Error Code: invalid_request
>
> Error Message: The required "redirect_uri" parameter is missing.

Not sure where or how in my code I should be submitting the redirect_uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a callback url as option.

From [passport-wordpress](https://github.com/mjpearson/passport-wordpress)

```
The strategy requires a verify callback, which accepts these credentials and 
calls done providing a user, as well as options specifying a client ID, 
client secret, and callback URL.
```

And from `lib/strategy.js`

```
Examples:

  passport.use(new WordpressStrategy({
      clientID: '123-456-789',
      clientSecret: 'shhh-its-a-secret',
      callbackURL: 'https://www.example.net/auth/wordpress/callback'
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      User.findOrCreate(..., function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
      });
    }
  ));
```

Comment: That worked!  Thank you.  One small typo: You need a comma after the secret line:
 clientSecret: 'shhh-its-a-secret',